# How to persist a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, persistent-storage

I'm absolutely new to iOS Dev.
I started out with the really helpful tutorial on [Apple dev website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1)

So i made the simple To-Do List application, as per instructions.

**The App:** It's a simple to-do list. It has a view, with a single text-field, which takes in an input, which then appends that input to the table-list view. the table list view is my "TO-Do List" which is generated from a NSMutableArray.

**The Problem:** Whenever i quit and relaunch the application, my List disappears.

**The Question:** I need a way to persist the `NSMutableArray *ToDoList` which stores my list.

So is it possible to persist the list? or will i have to make use of some kind of datastore?
I did a little research before asking and read something about storing the list in 'NSUserDefaults' - but the problem being, NsUserDefaults, only returns an **im-mutable Object**

Conclusion:

1. Can we persist the NsMutable List? If yes how?
2. Is NSUserDefaults necessary to use? Why?
3. If (2) is yes, then how do i make the returned immutable object of NsUserDefaults mutable?

Yet again i should tell you, that the only hands on iOS dev i have is from the tutorial. So i would love it if you break it down to the simplest form.

Thank you.

Comment: `NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key"]mutableCopy]`

Comment: I'd go against using NSUserDefaults, as To-do list sould be expanding in your app, & you might want to perform several operations on those objects. Everytime fetching data from userDefaults dont seem good approach to me.

Comment: Core Data. Learn it now - you'll be thankful for it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you just want to save an `NSMutableArray`, then yes, you can use `NSUserDefaults`.

2) If you don't want to deal with Core Data and set up a proper data structure, then it seems like that's the only option.

3) When you get an `NSMutableArray` from an `NSArray *array`, just use `[array mutableCopy]`.

Comment: It isn't the only option, you can write the array to a plist, as long as the array only contains plist-able objects. Alternatively, you could make your custom object conform to NSCoding and use `archiveDataWithRootObject:` to save the array to a file on disk.

Answer (score 2):

You can better go for CoreData. Its really easy to implement & great to use.

Here is the [best tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) to get started off

Here is the [Core Data programming guide from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

And here is [why you should go for Core-Data](http://sealedabstract.com/code/you-should-use-core-data/)

Despite of all other opinions, I'll suggest you to use core data only. It seemed too easy with visual interface provided in XCode & tons of great development support.

I'd go against using NSUserDefaults, as To-do list should be expanding in your app, & you might want to perform several operations on those objects. Everytime fetching data from userDefaults don't seem good approach to me.

**Why Use NSUserDefaults:**

The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences. For example, you can allow users to determine what units of measurement your application displays or how often documents are automatically saved. Applications record such preferences by assigning values to a set of parameters in a user’s defaults database. The parameters are referred to as defaults since they’re commonly used to determine an application’s default state at startup or the way it acts by default.

Here is [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thats exactly what i had in mind. A to-do list will expand, and saving and retrieving it every time seems like a broken concept. Another opinion i'd like,What exactly is NSUserDefaults used for?

Comment: You should use NSUserDefaults if you want to persist some user based settings, that are to changed less frequently & that too, they should not be bulky.

Comment: @Leo I've added more info regarding NSUserDefaults in my answer. Feel free to accept/upvote the answer if you agree with the points. Let me know if more info needed. Cheers :)

Comment: Another advantage - Core Data lets you store custom objects, whereas you can only store plist-able objects in NSUserDefaults or a plist on disk.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use the NSArray's writeToURL:atomically: and arrayWithContentsOfURL: methods to write your array to and read your array from a file on disk. A longer answer would justify where that might be… For now I'll skip to the answer: "to a file in a (unique to your app) folder in the '~/Library/Application Support/' folder. (Note: I'm an OSX programmer… there may be a better place for iOS apps… ;-) Here's code:

```
NSArray * array;    // <<== this is your array (I assume you've created it somewhere…)

// get the document directory URL
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentsDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];


// append our file name
NSURL *url = [documentDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ToDo.data" isDirectory:NO];

#if WRITING_ARRAY
    // write our array to the file
    if (![array writeToURL:url atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to writeToURL:'%@'", url);
    }
#else // READING_ARRAY
    // read (mutable) array from file
    array = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url] mutableCopy];
#endif
```

Comment: I've edited this to be more appropriate for an iOS app.

Comment: I am using the above code for storing NSMutableArray and when I try to retrieve the data from the .data file, I get nil.

Comment: Kunal Shrivastava: Check your console to see if the writeToURL posted any failure messages. Just to double check do the arrayWithContentsOfURL immediately after the writeToURL and compare what's read with what was written. Obviously, they should be the same; if they're not then again, check the console for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `Core Data`, or some other persistence way like `FMDB`. Use `NSUserDefaults` is okay but `NSUserDefaults` has really poor performance. You can do the demo using `NSUserDefaults`, but for the final app, a better way is strongly recommended.