# How to make a NSMutableArray persist over time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a brand-new iOS developer and have no previous experience with Objective-C, though I'm familiar with the C programming language and the Object-Oriented Programming paradigm.

To begin I followed the [*Start Developing iOS Apps Today*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html) tutorial and developed a basic to-do list app where each item is a `NSMutableString` object stored in a `NSMutableArray`. My app is working properly. However, my to-do list disappear when I quit and relaunch the app on the simulator. Obviously this happens because I provided no way to make the array persist over time.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072629/how-to-persist-a-nsmutablearray) there's a solution to this problem using `NSUserDefaults`, but I've seen that it's not an efficient solution, mostly because `NSUserDefaults` is made specifically for storing user's preferences and has very poor performance. Therefore I'm searching for another, still simple and straightforward solution to make my app more professional. Despite this fact, I'm having some trouble in understanding where (i.e. in which classes and methods) to put the code to achieve that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To make the data persist over time, I suggest you check out `NSCoding` and also `CoreData`. Both of them are simple to use and implement.

NSCoding [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data)

CoreData [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Even if there are solutions like `CoreData` that are specific to solve this problem, you might want something more light and quick to implement, but still cleaner than saving junk in the *User Defaults*.

NSMutableArray is [**NSCoding**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html) compliant, so as long as the items it contains are **NSCoding** compliant as well, you can easily store it in a file and retreive it back with the methods

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
- (NSArray *)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```

Bear in mind that you might have problems if you're storing primitive types like boolean values, so I advice to save them with an NSNumber instead.

Comment: Thank you. Now the problem is that I don't know where to use these methods. My array is being created in the `viewDidLoad` method and prepopulated with some initial data. So I have to use the method `initWithContentsOfFile` inside `viewDidLoad`. What about the writing process? Where does it have to be put?

Comment: well this depends on your needs and on the architecture of your app. You might want to load it in any init / viewDidLoad method and you might want to store it on any change, it's up to you to decide when save / load.